# Get received PUSH notification list without tap on the notification

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

when i open the app ,I need to read all the push notifications which are received when phone is not active or background mode. "**didReceiveRemoteNotification**" method call when the notification tapped only, i want to read the notification without tapping

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Returns a list of the app’s notifications that are still displayed in Notification Center.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { (notificationRequests) in
            for x in notificationRequests {
            print(x.request.content.body)
        }
        })
```

*Here is apple doc link*
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649520-getdeliverednotifications

**Another way**

These all remote push notification, pushed by your **backend server** via **Apple cloud server**. Better you request to your server to retrive all push notification payload in response and display to your client, Here you manage as per your need.

And then you clear notifications from notification tray.. like this.

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0 // For Clear Badge Counts
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications() // To remove all delivered notifications
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

Comment: Ahh i will try that, Thanks a lot for the answer, but isn't there any ways to loop all the received push notifications

Comment: `didReceiveRemoteNotification` doesn't get called until user taps on the notification.

Comment: @Nithaparan I have updated my answer.. can you please try other way to do it.

Comment: @Nithaparan.. Can you please give us feedback. whether this solution is working or not.

Comment: @SachinVsSachin getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler:) worked.
Thanks a lot

Comment: let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: { (notificationRequests) in
                print(notificationRequests[0].request.content.body)
            })

we can loop through  notificationRequests array